# test for uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{xn + \sqrt{n}}{n+x} \cdot ln(1+\frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}})$

1) when $0<x<1$

2) when $x>1$

So I noticed that $ln(1+\frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}})$ is equal to $\frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}}$ because $\frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$ and multiplying $\frac{xn + \sqrt{n}}{n+x}$ and $\frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}}$I got $\frac{x^2 \sqrt{n} + x}{n^2 + xn}$

So when $0<x<1$ we can say that $\frac{x^2 \sqrt{n} + x}{n^2 + xn} < \frac{\sqrt{n} + 1}{n^2 + n}$ and using Weierstrass M-test series converge uniformly.

What can I do when $x>1$ and did I make any mistakes when $0<x<1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint  for the POINTWISE convergence.

When $n\to +\infty$,

Your general term is equivalent to

$$\frac{nx}{n}\frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

if we take higher degrees for the rational fraction and use $ln(1+X) \sim X  \;\; (X\to 0)$,

or

$$\frac{x^2}{n\sqrt{n}}$$ wich is a positive  general term of a convergent series since $\frac{3}{2}>1$.